# Builder unable to find newly created button

Tags: c++11, gtk

After creating an object using :

```
GtkWidget* New = gtk_button_new_with_label("new");
```

and setting the name of the widget using:

```
gtk_widget_set_name(New, "new");
```

`application->get_object("new")` is still returning null. What am I doing wrong? : **(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gtk::Builder::get_object(const Glib::ustring& name)` looks for a object in a ui text file. You can write a ui file with Glade, https://glade.gnome.org/index.html.

However, when you write

```c
GtkWidget* New = gtk_button_new_with_label("new-name");
gtk_widget_set_name(New, "new-name");
```

you create a label and give it a name. But the label is not in the ui file. So you won't be able to find it from your `Gtk::Builder` instance. What the name "new-name" allows is that you can refer to it as "new-name" in a CSS file, so you can change its theme(font, background color etc).

These are two separate things.